# How to specify newCommandTimeout device capability in appium.exe gui

Tags: appium

I'm new to Appium. I started appium.exe on Windows and able to write some simple Java code to send some commands to the device using Appium API.

Problem is, while I'm inspecting something, Appium server sends my app to background by pressing Home button after 60 seconds when it receives no new commands.

I inspected appium  doc and google results but couldn't find how to specify newCommandTimeout capability to 0 in appium.exe. I don't want to do this in my Java code because I may forget to remove it later.

Here is my settings page on Appium gui: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the below code in your device capability:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, can it be done in appium.exe gui?

Comment: In settings, there is an  option "New Command Timeout"....tick this option in the gui

Comment: I don't see this option in the GUI. Added the screenshot. I downloaded Appium gui a couple of days ago. I think it does not exist in Windows version.

Comment: actually, if you add this in your desired capability, it will work same like gui option.

Comment: u can checkout like below:   Navigate to the following directory in your appium installation
AppiumForWindows-\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\

Open up the appium.js file and edit the following parameters.

  this.defCommandTimeoutMs = this.args.defaultCommandTimeout;
  this.commandTimeoutMs = this.defCommandTimeoutMs;
as follows

  this.defCommandTimeoutMs = this.args.defaultCommandTimeout * 5000;
  this.commandTimeoutMs = this.defCommandTimeoutMs * 5;
this will be enough to run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **newCommandTimeout** in Desired Capablities of device which you define in your code and not in the runtime argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I didn't get the reason why I can specify the device to connect or activity to launch but not the newCommandTimeout..

Answer (score 0):

In GUI mode, you can set New command timeout in advanced settings. This option is only available in MAC not windows and you should increase it instead of decreasing it. refer screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't see it in Windows version of the GUI. Added my screenshot to the original post above.

Comment: Yes you are right, as i have mentioned in my answer before this option is only available in MAC not windows. In windows we don't have any option to increase the timeout so we need to keep on sending some commands to appium by using refresh/tap/send keys etc.